# Large String seems to wrap when I dont want it to

Tags: c#, string, word-wrap

I am creating a long string in my c# application. I want it to stay on one line as these are the headers for fields the user has selected to update in the database.
The string will be used in a log file.

When I select all the fields to be updated it seems that the string is to long to be displayed in a single line and is automatically wrapped.

I am confused as textfile should be able to handle a string of any length (Memory permitting) without wrapping.

It seems that once the string gets longer than about 1050 characters it does an Automatic wrap.

My code is below:

```
private void UpdateCustomer(string pCurrentFileName, ref StringBuilder log, string date, ref string directoryPath, ref string logFilePath)
{
    // set the logfile paths for customer update
    directoryPath = Path.Combine(pLogFilePath, "CustomerUpdate_Log_" + date.Replace("/", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", ""));
    logFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "CustomerUpdate.log");
    DataSet customerUpdateDataSet = new CustomerUpdateValidator().ImportCustomersForUpdateFromExcelFileToDataSet(pCurrentFileName);

    log.Append("-------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n");
    log.Append("Bulk Maintenance Log: Customer Updatess" + "\r\n");
    log.Append("-------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "\r\n");
    log.Append(date + "\r\n\r\n");
    log.Append("Total number of Customer to be updated: " + (customerUpdateDataSet.Tables["CustomerData"].Rows.Count - 2).ToString() + "\r\n\r\n");
    log.Append("Data to be Inserted" + "\r\n");
    log.Append("-".PadRight(300, '-') + "\r\n\r\n\r\n");

    StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder("Row".PadRight(10, ' ') + "\t");
    header.Append("URN".PadRight(40, ' ') + "\t");

    int count = 0;
    // for each row in the grid view
    for (int i = 0; i < this.gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
    {
        // if the value is checked
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "CheckMarkSelection")))
        {
            // get the fields from the checked column
            string baxiDescription = this.gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "SimpleName").ToString();
            int size = getSizeFromType(this.gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "Type").ToString());
            header.Append(baxiDescription.PadRight(size, ' ') + "\t");
            count = i;
        }
    }

    header.Append("Result".PadRight(10, ' ') + "\t");
    header.Append("Reason".PadRight(30, ' ') + "\t");

    log.Append(header.ToString() + "\r\n");
    log.Append(new StringBuilder("-".PadRight(header.Length + 60, '-') + "\r\n"));
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

My DataSet:

[image]

Wrapped LogFile:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a client issue rather than being part of the data. What are you displaying this in?

Comment: Agree with Jon, look in a hex viewer or something that show CR-LFs so you see if there really is a line break there.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Im displaying it in a memoedit devexpress control. It is also saved as a text file which wraps at exactly the same point in the string as the memo edit.
I noticed that during debugging it also does the same thing in the watch window

Comment: In that case it sounds like the data itself probably contains line breaks.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Ok I checked out the generated logfile in Ultra edit and the format is fine so you are right about it being a client issue. Any suggestions as to how i can allow notepad to display this correctly?

Comment: @ComicCoder: Not offhand. I thought there was an option within "View" or something similar, but I can't remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that as I am saving my generated string into a .txt file and then opening the textfile in my logfile browser that the problem is related to .txt files and not actually my code